# Need jQuery Fancybox to refresh parent window

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm having a problem getting jQuery Fancybox to refresh the parent window once I'm done with it.  The fancybox opens and operates just fine, but the onClosed event won't work for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a#add_document_type").fancybox({
    type: 'iframe',
    onClosed: function() {
      parent.location.reload(true); 
    }
  });
});
```

For testing I've replaced parent.location.reload(true); with alert('Testing'); and had no luck there either so I'm at a bit of a loss.  Thanks for any help anyone can provide!

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED: the trick is to use afterClose:, not onClosed: so the full code would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a#add_document_type").fancybox({
    type: 'iframe',
    afterClose: function() {
      parent.location.reload(true); 
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `onClosed` is for fancybox v1.3.x while `afterClose` for v2.x

Comment: thank you very much. I was looking for this for hours. you are life saver :)